# Binding a Menu Item to a property of the First Responder

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, menuitem, cocoa-bindings, nsdocument

I have a document-based application.

In my document class,

- I have a BOOL property : `isActionPossible`.
- I also have an IBAction : `- (IBAction) doTheAction:(id)sender`.

Now, in `MainMenu.xib`, I want to connect a menu item to the action.
This is easy, when you know that the First Responder in Interface Builder "stands for" the active document of your application.

**But how shall I do to bind the availability** (the "enable property") **of this item menu with the BOOL property `isActionPossible` of the active document ?**

Indeed, in the list proposed, there isn't "First Responder".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two choices:

1. You can implement menu validation, see [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html). In short before a menu is displayed the system sends a validation request to the same object that handles the action, which includes the first responder. You simply add a method to your document class which returns a `BOOL`; in your case your `isActionPossible` property.
2. Use the `currentDocument` property of `NSDocumentController` which returns the document associated with the main window. You can then use bindings to bind `<Document Controller>.currentDocument.isActionPossible`. This approach is more general as you can bind label contents to values etc. as well as use it for menu bindings.

Comment: "Add a property to your document controller": do you mean I have to subclass `NSDocumentController`?

Comment: @Colas - There is no need to subclass `NSDocumentController`, I've updated the answer to make this clear.